# Provide custom AVR dude commands through the Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, avrdude, ide

Besides the standard upload button that burns the code using FTDI, I want to then be able to provide custom AVRDude commands for burning fuses, when the external programmer is used.

Is this possible to do from the IDE? Maybe if I can edit some configuration files?

The idea is to have the IDE supply the upload command when the standard upload option is selected, but when `external programmer` is selected, i want to have custom behavior.

The custom behavior that I want is to preserve the EEPROM and set the lock bit.

These two actions can be performed with the following AVRDude commands:

```
avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U hfuse:w:0xd2:m
avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U lock:w:0x00:m
```

The external programmer i use is Sparkfun's "Pocket AVR Programmer" which is an SPI programmer.

So can I have custom behavior (supported by AVRDude) when I select program using external programmer?

EDIT:
I opened file `boards.txt` and i found these specifications of interest:

```
pro.name=Arduino Pro or Pro Mini

pro.upload.tool=avrdude
pro.upload.protocol=arduino

pro.bootloader.tool=avrdude
pro.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
pro.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

pro.build.board=AVR_PRO
pro.build.core=arduino
pro.build.variant=eightanaloginputs
```

and

```
## Arduino Pro or Pro Mini (3.3V, 8 MHz) w/ ATmega328P
## ---------------------------------------------------
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328=ATmega328P (3.3V, 8 MHz)

pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.upload.maximum_size=30720
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.upload.speed=57600

pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xFD
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328_pro_8MHz.hex

pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.build.mcu=atmega328p
pro.menu.cpu.8MHzatmega328.build.f_cpu=8000000L
```

I am using Arduino Pro Mini.
In the second specification, there is the option for setting the fuse bits I want. However, there is no option for the lock bits.
The option for the lock bits are in the first specification - but there is no option for the fuses.

My new questions are these:

1. Should I specify the lock bits in the first specs and the fuses in the second? Will this work? I have to ask before trying anything stupid. Will the second specs "inherit" from the first specs?
2. Will the parameters I insert here only work for the `Upload Using Programmer` option? I want the regular upload (via bootloader) to work normally.
3. What happens if I ditch the Arduino platform and use a standalone AVR? If I use the same AVR that the Pro Mini platform had. Will the same settings work?

Comment: https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.27/platform-specification/#burn-bootloader or https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.27/platform-specification/#upload-using-an-external-programmer ?

Comment: Well, what i would like to be able to do is this: Preserve the EEPROM data, upload the program and then write the lock byte. There are three distinct AVRDude commands for performing these actions. I was wondering if i could modify the IDE, so that everytime you hit the upload button, it also preserves the EEPROM data and sets the lock byte.

Comment: I can't test it now, but you could add the fuse parameters to the `tools.avrdude.program.pattern` in platform.txt. Copy them from the `tools.avrdude.erase.pattern`. note: the fuse values are in boards.txt

Comment: So the `tools.avrdude.program.pattern` is what will happen when i program the arduino? And what are the contents of `tools.avrdude.erase.pattern`? What will the behaviour be after i copy them? I want three distinct steps (preserve EEPROM, upload, set lock bit). I updated the question with AVRDude commands, of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Juraj I think I am getting closer. I edited the question. Could you please take a look at it? I have three sub-questions that are really quickly answered. Thank you very much!

Comment: those are not two specs in boards txt. all the pro.* keys values are applied, but some depend on the selection in CPU options in the Tools menu (like the fuses) while some are valid for all CPU options (lock bits)

Comment: @Juraj So if i use The Arduino Pro Mini, then it means i have to modify the first set for the lock bits, and the second set for the fuse values? Will this work? Also, does this work ONLY for the `external programmer` option?

Comment: you have to modify the `tools.avrdude.program.pattern` in platform.txt to add the parameter you want to be applied for "Upload with programmer". `tools.avrdude.program.pattern` is only for "Upload with programmer".

Comment: OK. These are its contents:`tools.avrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} {program.verify} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"`. Where and how exactly do i specify the lock bit and the fuses in there? I cannot find any reference on the internet, and the syntax is not obvious.

Comment: how is it not obvious? {cmd.path} is path to avrdude and those are parameters for avrdude, just the keys are not replaced with values. for pro mini it evaluates to `avrdude -Cavrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cusbtiny -Uflash:w:Blink.ino.hex:i`

Comment: Thanks! Some parts are still not obvious. For example, how do I add a separator in the -U flag? I also want to pass `hfuse:w:0xd2:m` and `lock:w:0x00:m`. Finally, I should keep a copy of the original string, just in case I want to revert back to a normal operation. I mean, these are global settings, right?

Comment: as I already wrote, you can see the fuses parameters in  `tools.avrdude.erase.pattern`. you can copy from there

Comment: I know the fuse parameters, i have them in the question as well. I just don't know how to put them in the one liner on `tools.avrdude.program.pattern`. There are three parameters, fuses, lock bit and hex file. How do i separate them? What the correct command should be like?

Comment: and I say third time:  see the erase.pattern in platform.txt for the fuse parameters `tools.avrdude.erase.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {erase.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} -e -Ulock:w:{bootloader.unlock_bits}:m -Uefuse:w:{bootloader.extended_fuses}:m -Uhfuse:w:{bootloader.high_fuses}:m -Ulfuse:w:{bootloader.low_fuses}:m`

Comment: You said:
`you have to modify the tools.avrdude.program.pattern in platform.txt to add the parameter you want to be applied for "Upload with programmer".`
The parameters i want applied are
`-U hfuse:w:0xd2:m
-U lock:w:0x00:m`
The erase params is what you just posted. You say this string should go to `tools.avrdude.pattern`.
I searched for example, for `bootloader.high_fuses`. These are in `boards.txt`. The values i found were not what i wanted. I want `hfuse:w:0xd2`. Where do i set this value? This is what i am asking.

Comment: so for a test modify boards.txt. what I don't know is if avrdude will apply these fuse parameters

Comment: Just did a test. In `boards.txt`, in the `Pro Mini` section, I changed `pro.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F` to `pro.bootloader.lock_bits=0x00` but unfortunately it didn't work, as I was able to read the flash. I guess it is not doable from inside the IDE.

Comment: it worked https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-cannot-set-lock-bits-and-fuses-from-ide/1034159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the fuse parameters to the "Upload using programmer" command pattern `tools.avrdude.program.pattern` in platform.txt. Copy them from the `tools.avrdude.erase.pattern`. (The fuse values are from boards.txt)

the modified upload command pattern:

> tools.avrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} {program.verify} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i" -Ulock:w:{bootloader.lock_bits}:m

Comment: Is there a way to get the IDE to reload this file? I edit it and it seems like I need to close and reopen the IDE to get my changes to apply...

Comment: @ldoogy, yes, it requires to restart the IDE